# How do I solve this? Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

I've been stuck for a while on this. I'm not sure how to solve these problems. Please help me out. Here are the errors from the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at Main.main(Main.java:35)
```

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Main{
    
   public static void main(String[] args){
       
       //new Player object
       Player player = new Player();
       
       //open text file
       File roomFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Khari\\eclipse-workspace\\MiniGame1\\src\\room.txt");
       
       //open a Scanner to read data from File
       Scanner roomReader = null;
       
       try{
           roomReader = new Scanner(roomFile);
       }
       catch (FileNotFoundException e){
           System.out.println("Room.txt file has not been found");
       }
       
       // read one value at a time
       while(roomReader != null && roomReader.hasNext()){
           
           //assign values to attributes
           int id = roomReader.nextInt();
           String desc = roomReader.nextLine();
           String visitedString = roomReader.nextLine();
           boolean visited = Boolean.parseBoolean(visitedString);
           
        //add new objects to the array list
           Room room = new Room(id, desc, visited);

       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Which one is line 35? And what was the input?

Comment: But it looks like the file does not contain an `int` where you expect one to be. Maybe consider something like json or XML as dataformat, so you do not need to parse the file manually.

Comment: I would recommend running the code in a debugger to see when the exception pops up, such that you could inspect the current variable state (and what is currently loaded in the `Scanner`'s buffer). Debuggers are very useful for this, and most IDEs include some form of debugging tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a counter to increment & print it on first line inside the `while` loop to know the line number of the file. When you get the error, you know the line number printed in console. Then keeping only limited no. of line around the error line & removing other content of file you can debug to find the reason.